# What output to feed

Tags: video-quality

My question offloading video to composite video for Video 8 (in shot)to view on plane, if my hdmi > SD converter output is 576i50 should I set my source output as high as poss (2160p60 or 50) or should I output 576p50 so there is less for the converter to do? Appreciate any advice.